# Javascript File API Reading into buffer

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, fileapi

I am interested on reading from file to my own buffer, in order to avoid an additional copy.

There seems to be an experimental technology [ReadableStreamBYOBReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamBYOBReader). I tested in MS edge that is expected to support accordingly to [Browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamBYOBReader#browser_compatibility), as well as [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_readablestreambyobreader_readablestreambyobreader).

Here is the snippet that I expected to run in a browser supporting the feature, can you spot an error or explain why it is not working?

```js
console.log(navigator.userAgent)

document.querySelector('#input-file').addEventListener('change', async (e) => {
  if(e.target.files[0]){
    try{
      // Compare two methods of reading a file
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      const stream = file.stream();
      const slice = await file.slice(0, Math.min(file.size, 16)).arrayBuffer()
      const my_own_array = new Uint8Array(Math.min(file.size, 16));
      // Here is where it fails in my browser
      const reader = stream.getReader({mode:'byob'})
      console.log(await reader.read(my_own_array));
      slice_array = new Int8Array(slice);
      // I expect both arrays to have the same data since I read the same file
      console.log({allEqual: slice_array.every((v, i) => v === my_wn_array[i])})
      console.log(my_own_buffer);
      
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e.toString())
    }
  }
})
```

```html
Select a file and the script will attempt to load it

<input type=file id=input-file>
```

What I see here is

```txt
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36 Edg/94.0.992.38`
TypeError: Failed to execute 'getReader' on 'ReadableStream': Cannot use a BYOB reader with a non-byte stream
```

If it works in your browser, please, let me know in the comments.

*EDIT*: As noted by `Xeelley` I should have passed `{mode:'byob'}` instead of `'byob'`.

Answer (score 0):

Check MDN [ReadableStream.getReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader) Docs.

`getReader` accept 1 optional parameter with type `object`. So if you need BYOB reader, you should pass reader config like this:

```js
file.stream().getReader({ mode: 'byob' })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that took one step further, now can you tell why how to construct a byte stream from the file?